# problem with the result of a sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following scenario to achieve using SQL statement ,
I have an issue assigned to groups Triage,GX,GY:

group Triage --> group GX

group GX -->group Triage

group Triage --> group GY

I want to extract just the first time when my issue is assigned to group Triage and ignore the rest , I have tried to do that but always bad result(retrive all rows when the issue assigned to Triage group )

SQL Statement:

```
    select g.created ,ji.pkey as issueName
    from   changegroup g
    join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
    join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
    join   project p on (p.id = ji.project)
    join   priority pr on (pr.id = ji.priority)
    where  ci.field = 'Group'
    and  ci.oldString = 'Triage' 
    and  p.pname = 'Test'
    and pr.pname='P3'
    and  ji.created between '2011-08-11 14:01:00' and  '2011-08-12 14:11:00'
```

the result of the statement (as you see ,the issue 200 is assigned to group Triage 2 times so the request retrieve 2 rows):

[image]

The table changegroup has this structure:

[image]

The table changeitem has this structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. But it can be very slow query

```
select g.created, ji.pkey as issueName
from   changegroup g
join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
where (g.created, issueName) in (
 select min(g.created) ,ji.pkey as issueName
 from   changegroup g
 join   changeitem ci on (ci.groupid = g.id)
 join   jiraissue ji on (ji.id = g.issueid)
 join   project p on (p.id = ji.project)
 join   priority pr on (pr.id = ji.priority)
 where  ci.field = 'Group'
 and  ci.oldString = 'Triage' 
 and  p.pname = 'Test'
 and pr.pname='P3'
 and  ji.created between '2011-08-11 14:01:00' and  '2011-08-12 14:11:00'
 group by issueName
)
```